# Mongodb save create new collection

Tags: mongodb

For some strange reason, I cannot create a new collection. Here is what I did:

```
use newdb
switched to db newdb
db.getCollectionNames()
[ ]
db.teams.save({country:"Ukraine",GroupName:"D"})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 18825,
        "errmsg" : "couldn't create file /data/db/newdb.ns"
    }
})
```

I could save to any other DB or collections that I've already created however.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a file/directory permissions error. Does the `mongod` process have full write+create permissions in `/data/db`?

Comment: Yeah! It looks like it could be the issue, but how do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have created folder /data/db and it has relevant permissions. Basically mongodb is trying to save all metadata files in /data/db folder. Either /data/db its not present or its not having permissions to write on.

You can do following in terminal to check the error more specifically :

tail -50 /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

Check the owner of the file :

sudo chown -r mongodb:mongodb /data/db

Check permissions of the folder :

sudo chmod 775 -r /data/db

Comment: Here is the permission:drwxr-xr-x  33 498   496    1122  4 Aug  2016 db/

Comment: How would I give permission to write for just that process?

Comment: sudo chmod 775 -R /data/db